# Python: trying to use 'count' to limit the amount of lines "print" will output

Tags: python, count, while-loop

I have a script that will walk a system directory, and get the files sizes in that directory. it then sorts by the file size(descending), takes two arguments.  The first arg is the system path and the second arg is an integer to limit the output to that integer count.

I'm using a while loop to limit the print output but its getting stuck in a infinite loop.... obviously, something is wrong but i cant see it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

#Grab arguments 
mydir = sys.argv[1]
mycnt = sys.argv[2]

print mydir 
print mycnt
#set base dir
root_path = mydir


fileSize = 0
rootdir = mydir
filedict = dict()
count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root,file)
        filesize = fileSize + os.path.getsize(filepath)
        filedict[filepath] = filesize


for key, value in sorted(filedict.iteritems(), key=lambda (key,val): (val,key), reverse=True):
    while (count <= mycnt):
        print "(%8s)" "     (%-8s)" % (value, key)
        count += 1
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mycnt` is a string, not an integer (which it is when read directly from `sys.argv`), your loop will never end.

Comment: ahhh....right, thank you...completely overlooked that. added "mycnt = int(mycnt)"

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, the *[repr](http://docs.python.org/library/repr.html#module-repr)* module has tools to display a list while limiting the number of lines of output.

Comment: thanks Raymond, yes -- will def look at that...hate having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You should have an `if` instead of `while`.

You want to exit the program *if* `count <= mycnt`.

Comment: feel free to upvote the answers that help you.. that's what SO is all about :)

Answer (score 1):

You added the `else` clause to the `while` loop. It will execute only if the `while` loop never executes.

Your `while` loop terminates as `count` increases past `mycnt`, and anoter iteration of `for` loop is executed. Mabe you just don't notice it ­— your `for` loop may take long.

Answer (score 1):

[Larry Lustig has already hit the nail on the head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102177/python-trying-to-use-count-to-limit-the-amount-of-lines-print-will-output/8102190#8102190) regarding `mycnt`, but your check to see if you've hit the limit is also wrong (as [Hamish points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102177/python-trying-to-use-count-to-limit-the-amount-of-lines-print-will-output/8102203#8102203)).

Rather than `if (count <= mycnt):`, you could use a [slice](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) like `[:maximum]`, removing the need for the `count` variable. Speaking of variables, I suggest that you would benefit from some better-named variables. *Viz*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

rootdir = sys.argv[1]
maximum = int(sys.argv[2])

print 'Printing the biggest ', maximum, 'files in', rootdir, '...'

filedict = {}
for root, _, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filepath)
        filedict[filepath] = filesize

sorted_by_size = sorted(filedict.iteritems(), key=lambda(path, size): (size, path), reverse=True)
for path, size in sorted_by_size[:maximum]:
     print "(%8s)      (%-8s)" % (size, path)
```

Comment: Jonny, thanks very much for showing me a cleaner way -- much appreciated.  Yes, I agree with the variable names comment, I always have trouble coming up with names -- and lean to the more obscure names.  Also, I had no idea that i could throw sys.argv into int() -- I LOVE python :-D