# Writing files with a numerical indicator in the name; Python

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I have a script that scrapes some webpages and writes a .csv file with that data. Pseudocode:

```
def Function(web_pages):
    for page in web_pages:
        scrape page
        analyse page
        write .csv output
```

The problem is that I want to leave run the script running for a few months to scrape the data every day, so I need some method of writing files with discernible history.

Right now I have

```
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_now = time_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

with open(os.path.join('/MyPath/','%s_data%s.csv' % (page,time_now)), 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
    w.writerow(['HEADERS'])
    w.writerows(izip(my_lists))
```

This serves the purpose, however it creates a file with a monstrous name like `page_data2016-02-15_13/53/58.csv`.

What I would prefer infinitely more, is to have files with names like `page1_data_1.csv`, `page1_data_2.csv`, `page1_data_3.csv`, `page2_data_1.csv`, `page2_data_2.csv`, and so on...

However, even though it seems like a trivial problem, I can't really think of a way of implementing this method of saving files.
Thanks.

Forgot to mention:
I'm using `apscheduler.schedulers` to automate the process, so the function is called anew every time.

Here's where the function is called:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(Function, 'interval', minutes=30)
scheduler.start()
print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Comment: Personally I'd stick with the dated filenames. It lets you see any gaps in your data. If you really want to go numeric, maybe use `glob.glob()` to get a list of files for a particular page, use [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) to get the most recent file, strip out the index and add one to that.

Comment: Have you considered walking the directory, [counting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8102177/5903421) the files, and appending `count + 1` to the end of the file name? Something like `'%s%s_data_%s.csv' % (page, file_count + 1, page_count + 1)`...